# Show multiple charts at HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I need to show multiple charts using chart.js.

I know how many charts I need only after the user sends the data so I can't write different canvas-id at the HTML file(i don't know how many I need).

So my question is how can I show a number of charts without know it at the beginning? (every chart is a different row at the matrix)

my code:

```
<HTML>
<div class="chart-container">
              <div class="pie-chart-container">
                <canvas id="pie-chartcanvas-1"></canvas>
            </div>
         </div>

     <!-- javascript -->
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```

javascript

```
var piechart = $("#pie-chartcanvas-1");
     var data1 = {
     labels: itemsArr,
     datasets: [
     {
      label: "Population (millions)",
      backgroundColor:
      ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850","#3cba9f"],
      data: mat[0]
       }
       ]
       };

     var chart = new Chart(piechart,{
     type:"pie",
     data : data1,
     options:{
       title: {
          display: true,
          text: namesArr[0]
     }

   }});
```

Comment: You can create new canvas elements (or others) and append them to your document.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data the user sends you as the data1 object? Do you always need a pie chart? If so...

```
function createChart(data, id) {
  addCanvas(id); // some id generated by you or sent by the user
  generateChart(data, id); // data from the user
}

function addCanvas(id) { // create the new canvas
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canv.setAttribute("id", "canvasID");
  document.getElementsByClassName('pie-chart-container')[0].appendChild(canvas);
}   

function generateChart(data, id) { // initialize the new chart 
  let piechart = $("#" + id);
  let chart = new Chart(piechart,{
    type:"pie",
    data : data,
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: namesArr[0]
      }
    }
  });
}
```